# gitlab-runner exec docker - inject gpg key

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, gitlab

I need to run `gitlab-runner` locally using the `exec` command and the docker executor.

The docker executor clones the project into the container so I start with a blank slate. In order to run the tests, I need to decrypt certain credentials files. Normally this is done on the dev machine using the developers private gpg key. But now we are in a container and I can't find a way to inject the developers gpg key into the testing container.

Normally it would make sense to pass the private key as an environment variable but the `environment` feature is not supported on the `gitlab-runner exec` command.

It would be much easier if `gitlab-runner` would just copy the project files into the container instead of doing a fresh clone of the project. That way the developer would decrypt the credentials on the host and everything is fine.

What are my options here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only option to pass in environment variables into the testing container is to use the `--env` parameter for `gitlab-runner`.

First we need to store the private key in an environment variable on our local machine. I used `direnv` for this but it also works manually:

```
export GPG_PRIVATE_KEY="$(gpg --export-secret-keys -a <KEY ID>)"
```

Then we can run `gitlab-runner` like this:

```
gitlab-runner exec docker test \
  --env GPG_PRIVATE_KEY="$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY" \
  --env GPG_PASSPHRASE="$GPG_PASSPHRASE"
```

Note that I also passed the passphrase in an environment variable because I need it inside the container to decrypt my data.

Now I can import the key in the docker container. The top of my `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
image: quay.io/mhart/alpine-node:8

before_script:
  - apk add --no-cache gnupg
  - echo "$GPG_PRIVATE_KEY" | gpg --batch --import --pinentry-mode loopback --no-tty
```

Done, now we can use that key inside the container to do what we want.

I also ran into some problems when I tried to decrypt my data. [This guide](https://www.rzegocki.pl/blog/how-to-make-gnupg2-to-fall-in-love-with-docker/) was incredibly helpful and solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard for me to imagine.why you need to invoke gitlab-runner with exec but why could not you do

```
   exec gitlab-runner sh
             export GPG_KEY=...
             ....
```

Comment: No, `exec` is a sub-command from `gitlab-runner` that runs a gitlab-ci.yml on the local machine.

Comment: Ok i was thinking you meant 'docker container exec'.  I still dont think you want 'exec'.  It is not hard to create a gitlab container, register your runner with it, and push code triggering the gitlab-ci.  Probably easier than figuring out why 'exec' does not work.

Comment: But that are not the requirements. The requirement is that our external teams "just" have to run `gitlab-runner exec docker test` on their local machine and the proper tests will be triggered. If that doesn't work, I don't see the point in using any gitlab related software for that task at all.

Comment: You don't get it, right? I don't want to start a full GitLab just to use a tool that is supposed to be used without GitLab. If I want to run a docker container manually, then I can just start the application container and run my tests with a small bash script and don't need that `gitlab-runner` crapware at all.

Comment: You are right.  I do not get your use case.  Sorry that I could not be of assistance.